# probability of 4 of kind in 7 cards

Tags: probability

If $7$ cards are dealt with $2$ to the player and $5$ with the dealer. Now the  question is to find the probabability of having four of kind in dealt cards.

Per my understanding probability would remain same as it is quite similar to pulling $7$ cards from deck of $52$ cards. Be it be any sort of possibility like

- $2$ cards in hand of player and $2$ in $5$ dealer cards
- $1$ card in hand of player out of $2$, rest of $3$ cards in $5$ dealer cards

and so on

\begin{array}{l l}
\text{Hand of player} & \text{Dealer's cards}\\ \hline    
A\ \ A & A\ \ A\ \ x\ \ x \ \ x\\
A\ \ x & x\ \ A \ \ x\ \ A\ \ x\\
x\ \ A & A\ \ x\ \ x\ \ A\ \ x\\
x\ \ A & x\ \ x\ \ x\ \ A\ \ A
\end{array}

Where number of ways choosing rank is  $a = C(13,1)$

Number of ways one of rank have $4$ cards dealt $b= C(4,4)$

Other three cards can come in $c = 48 \cdot 47 \cdot 46$

Total number of ways $7$ cards could be drawn $d = C(52,7)$

Answer would be $\dfrac{abc}{d}$

Please rectify me if anyone thinks my way of approaching this problem is wrong.

Comment: The order in which the other three cards are dealt is irrelevant, so your value for $c$ should not be $48 \cdot 47 \cdot 46$ since that takes order into account.  Should we interpret four of a kind to mean that the other three cards can be of any rank, which would permit them to include a pair or three of a kind?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site using MathJax.

Comment: Thanks for input and tutorial link , here are just saying three card of any rank but they don't lead to any three  of kind  or full house etc.

Answer (score 3):

It's the number of ways to get four of a kind in seven cards divided by the number of ways of selecting seven cards from fifty two:
$$P(4oak7) = \frac{13\cdot ^{48}C_3}{^{52}C_7} = .0016807$$

Answer (score 2):

To vindicate Anup Bali's comment to Phil H's answer, and to show a different approach: Count not combinations but permutations; that is, the order in which the 7 cards were dealt matters. Then there are $13$ options for the rank that appears 4 times, ${}_4P_4$ orders to deal the 4 cards of that rank, ${}_{48}P_3$ possibilities for the three odd cards (this already takes account of order) and ${}_7C_4$ ways in which the 4-of-a-kind cards can be placed among the 7 cards. Thus the probability is
$$\frac{13\cdot{}_4P_4\cdot{}_{48}P_3\cdot{}_7C_4}{{}_{52}P_7}\approx .00168067.$$